# ADBannerView takes more space than normal

Tags: ios, swift, adbannerview

I have something strange in my app and since I'm a beginner with ADBannerView I hope somebody could help me.

I already configured in appDelegate.swift the methods to create and manage the ADBannerView, in my view I add this code:

```
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        appDelegate.adBannerView.center = CGPoint(x: view.frame.midX, y:  view.frame.height - appDelegate.adBannerView.frame.height / 2)

        view.addSubview(appDelegate.adBannerView)

        self.canDisplayBannerAds = true

    }
```

Then iAd is correctly shown in my view but also a 49px empty bar over it (the white one). How can I delete it? Is it part of the iAd? Any idea?

[Click to see the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O446l.png)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How are you instantiating your `bannerView`?

Comment: in "AppDelegate" i added "var adBannerView = ADBannerView()".
adBannerView.delegate = self, adBannerView.hidden = true and the functions bannerViewDidLoadAd, bannerViewActionDidFinish, bannerView. 
in my view i use let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate , so I can add to the main view appDelegate.adBannerView

Answer (score 2):

Thank you pbush25, I found the solution. I post it if others need it.

In appDelegate.swift

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, ADBannerViewDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
var adBannerView = ADBannerView()
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    adBannerView.delegate = self
    adBannerView.hidden = true
    return true
}


func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    print("bannerViewDidLoadAd")
    adBannerView.hidden = false
}

func bannerViewActionDidFinish(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    print("bannerViewActionDidFinish")
}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    print("didFailToReceiveAdWithError: \(error)")
    adBannerView.hidden = true
}
func bannerViewWillLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
    print("bannerViewWillLoadAd")
}

func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
    print("bannerViewActionShouldBegin")
    return true
}
```

and in every view I want to show iAd

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.defaultLoad()
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.defaultLoad()
}
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    appDelegate.adBannerView.delegate = nil
    view.removeFromSuperview()
}

func defaultLoad(){
    appDelegate.adBannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, (view.frame.height) - 99, (view.frame.size.width), 50) // 50(banner)+49(tab bar)
    appDelegate.adBannerView.delegate = appDelegate
    super.view.addSubview(appDelegate.adBannerView)
    super.view.bringSubviewToFront(appDelegate.adBannerView)
    super.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    super.canDisplayBannerAds = true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you instantiate your `ADBannerView` you should probably instantiate it with a frame:

```
var adBannerView = ADBannerView(frame: CGRectMake(0, (self.window?.frame.height)! - 50, (self.window?.frame.size.width)!, 50))
```

And then it should always be at that part of the whole `Window` of your app. Thus in your `viewDidLoad` you don't need to set the center, you'll just need to `self.view.addSubview(adBannerView)` and then probably `self.view.bringSubviewToFront(adBannerView)`

Comment: Thank you, i tried but it doesn't change. I use a Tab Bar Controller to switch between my view, could be that a problem? I tried with your suggestion into a view with no "tab bar" and it works right.
Seems like the height of the tab bar is duplicated on the top of the iAd

Comment: Then you might try -100 for it's y position. You might also try `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()` which might help to solve some layout problems.

Comment: I managed to understand that if I use more than one canDisplayBannerAds = true , for example in 2 or more tabs, the white bar appears. So i changed my code into super.view.addSubview(appDelegate.adBannerView);
        super.view.bringSubviewToFront(appDelegate.adBannerView);
        super.view.layoutIfNeeded();
        super.canDisplayBannerAds = true; but I dunno how to reuse the same adBannerView since I settled it to "super" instead of "self". And if I write into the other tab "super.canDisplayBannerAds = true;" I get the white bar in the first tab.